Design RGB strip with WS2813 on 24 V?
I am in the process of designing a PCB with RGB LEDs. I wanna control them with NeoPixel. And it has to be supplied with 24 V.
Right now for reference (see picture) I have a LED strip with segments of 6 LEDs that is supplied with 24 V. DIN is 5V as usual. The last LED in the series has 8 pins. Is that the one that enables the use of 24 V? - Because the normal WS2813 is running on 5 V?
Can someone point me in the right direction?


Given the voltage, it is probably a WS2811 or one of its cloned integrated into the last pixel.

It's not really a LED, it's a package with a driver chip and RGB LEDs. I guess they adopted that "camouflage" packaging to avoid having a missing LED in the strip where the driver chip would be. The question is... what driver chip is inside and how to get it...
When driving LEDs with a linear constant current driver, as these do, all the voltage drop in the driver corresponds to wasted power. So if your blue LED has a Vf of 3V and VCC=5V, it is wasting 2/5=40% of power, turning it into heat. Thus if you use a higher supply voltage like 24V, you really need to arrange your LEDs in series strings to increase the voltage on the LEDs and decrease wasted power in the driver. For example with 6 LEDs with Vf=3V we have 18V on the LEDs, 6V dropped by the driver, so only 6/24=25% of the power is wasted. By lowering supply voltage to 22V or so it can be even better. But you can't control the LEDs individually, it has to be in groups of 6.
Thus if you want individually addressable LEDs, I'd recommend using a buck converter to drop 24V to 4.5-5V with good efficiency, then 5V LEDs.
If you want the same 24V driver chip that's inside this multi-purpose LED, you can always try WS2811, which is the same chip that's inside WS2812 "LED". I'm not sure it is rated for 24V though. There are many other chips, some compatible with WS2812 some not. Try searching for "led pixel driver" or "individually addressable led driver" for example.
